# Message: Trying to get property of non-object when load same function on one view Codeignitter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to retrieve same data from one function on one view using codeignitter. But i get error message **Trying to get property of non-object**

this is my function which i want to call. this model have name **model_setting.php**

```
public function all(){
        //query semua record di table setting
        $hasil = $this->db->get('setting');
        if($hasil->num_rows() > 0){
            return $hasil->result();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }
```

below my controller where i call function **model_setting->all()**

```
public function index() {
        $this->load->model('model_setting');

        $data['setting']=$this->model_setting->all();
        $this->load->view('contact',$data);
    }
```

Then below code of view which i use to retrieve data

```
<?php foreach($setting as $setting) : ?>

  <p><strong><?=$setting->name?></strong>
      <br><?=$setting->address?>
      <br><?=$setting->email?>
      <br><?=$setting->telp?>

      <br>

  </p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I try to view same data using foreach syntax like above twice on same view on different position. On first position the data successfully show. But on the second position the error message "Message: Trying to get property of non-object" appear.

Is there another way to show same data on one view ?

Answer (score 1):

> On first position the data successfully show. But on the second position the error message

`foreach($setting as $setting)` is an invalid implementation of the [PHP `foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

On the first iteration of the loop, `$setting` is set to the first item in the original `$setting` array.  It appears to work since you're only using this first item.

```
// LOOP #1 
foreach($setting as $setting)
           ▲           ▲
           |           | sets $setting as $setting[0] // first item of array
       represents       
     original array
```

On the second iteration of the loop, the `$setting` variable no longer represents the original `$setting` array.  *Now* it represents the first item as designated by the first iteration loop, therefore you get a `non-object` error message when trying to find item #2.

```
// LOOP #2
foreach($setting as $setting)
           ▲           ▲ 
           |           | trying to set $setting as $setting[0][1] // looking for 2nd item
       represents              
       $setting[0] 
  as set in first loop
```

Should be `foreach(array_expression as $value)`...

```
<?php foreach($setting as $item) : ?>
    <p>
        <strong><?php echo $item->name; ?></strong>
        <br>
        <?php echo $item->address; ?>
        <br>
        <?php echo $item->email; ?>
        <br>
        <?php echo $item->telp; ?>
        <br>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I have try using same different name of variable in iteration like your describe above. But i'ts still no working. i got error message like this  " Message: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: @user2967389, your `foreach()` is clearly broken, and I cannot see what you did when you tried fixing it.  In other words, I cannot help you fix something I cannot see, and there is nothing else you've shown us that would explain why you continue to get this error message.